# .Net API in IIS (Azure VM) not browsing

Tags: iis, cicd, .net-4.8, applicationpoolidentity

I have a .net 4.8 api which is getting deployed in IIS (azure vm). The vm is domain joined and the app pool is using application pool identity.

When I deploy it, post that I am unable to browse the api swagger.

Here are some details:

1. I manually create a port 80 binding but cannot browse the api created under the site
2. VM is domain joined
3. App pool identity used
4. If I set physical path in Basic Settings for site I get an error:
   "The specified user name does not exist"

Tasks IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0 and IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0 used for deployment in release pipeline.

Edit 1:
Yaml

```
//params and variables defined while calling stage

baseUrl: mysite.com
RootPath: 'D:\myapp\${{ parameters.baseUrl }}'
VirtualApiPath: '/API'
Workspace: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/'
PackageName: '/drop/xxx/MyAPI.zip'

- task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'Manage Web Application'
  inputs:        
    IISDeploymentType: IISWebsite 
    ActionIISWebsite: 'CreateOrUpdateWebsite'
    WebsiteName: '${{ parameters.baseUrl }}'
    WebsitePhysicalPath: '${{ parameters.RootPath }}'
    CreateOrUpdateAppPoolForWebsite: true
    AppPoolNameForWebsite: 'MyAppPool'
    PipeLineModeForWebsite: 'Integrated'
    AppPoolIdentityForWebsite: 'ApplicationPoolIdentity'

- task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'Deploy Web Application'
  inputs:
    WebSiteName: ${{ parameters.baseUrl }}
    VirtualApplication: '${{ parameters.VirtualApiPath }}'
    Package: '${{ parameters.Workspace }}/**/${{ parameters.PackageName }}'
    TakeAppOfflineFlag: true
    XmlTransformation: true
    XmlVariableSubstitution: true
```

Comment: In the Test Connection I see Authentication is green (app pool identity is valid) but in Authorization has warning: The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built in account has access. Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to physical path. If server is joined to a domain, and the application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify that <domain>\<computer_name>$ has read access to physical path

Comment: I created a new site and added the physical path that worked fine. The difference between the one created by pipeline and manual is the folder set up: For manual: Site had the application (API: virtual path) which on expanding has bin and for the pipeline which does not work: there is a folder API again inside the application. However I am unable to point any difference in the task which creates the site and app. Adding the task details in question

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.